# How to check if my iPhone owned by MDM?

Tags: iphone, mdm, hacking

My iPhone feels lighter and heavier while connecting to the internet. It gets heated normally. I can feel that someone is monitoring my screen too. Might be my device gets targeted by remote MDM. Visibly i am not able to find any profile in the setting option. Is there any other way to detect if the device is owned by MDM?

Comment: It *feels* lighter and heavier?  You can *feel* someone is monitoring your screen?  How does one *feel* these things?  There are a couple of questions...how did you obtain the phone and did you "register" it with work and/or school accounts?

Comment: screen started blinking sometimes, unusual heating without much use! I brought it from Amazon and was registered (not MDM) with my office email and profile.

Comment: @Allan It's possible that the OP does not speak North American English, and that "lighter and heavier" is meant to imply "faster and slower"

Comment: Hi @peter.  I actually speak two languages (I joke that I speak 3 - English, Spanish, *and* American) and I can't think of any English region that would substitute "lighter" for "faster"  in this manner.  Even in Spansh, it would be "lento" for "slow".  These are typically words with direct translations.

Comment: See the answer below.  But, know that some organization *require* MDM to be installed (like Microsoft Intune) to access company resources.    That said, I haven't seen any that will mirror your screen to monitor you.  However, they may get activity reports.  The screen flashing may be a symptom of a poor repair/refurbishment.

Comment: @Allan In Indian English "prepone" is a perfectly cromulent word that is the antonym of "postpone". So I'm not taking any bets on how the OP uses English.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know American English, but I wrote what I meant. @Allan Thanks but as I mentioned there is no visible registered profile in the settings!

Comment: I spent the first part of my life in a British Commonwealth so, “American” is not my “first language”.   Your phone is  probably not managed by MDM.  A flickering screen is symptomatic of a hardware issue. Screen capture software grabs the image from the GPU, not the display itself.

Answer (score 2):

> You can see the profiles you have installed in Settings > General > VPN & Device Management. If you delete a profile, all of the settings, apps, and data associated with the profile are also deleted.

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/iph6c493b19/ios